# Updating an existing user's profile is creating a new user in Django connected with MongoDB

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I wrote this function to update existing user's profile but it is creating a new user instead of updating existing one. Would you please help to figure out the problem.

This is my update logic

```
def update_Profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
           address =request.POST['address']
           country=request.POST['country']
           city=request.POST['city']
           zipcode =request.POST['zipcode']
           dob=request.POST['dob']
           gender =request.POST['gender']
           weight =request.POST['weight']
           height =request.POST['height']

           if(request.session.has_key('user_id')):
                    userid = request.session['user_id']
                    if User_profile.objects.filter(email = userid).exists():
                      user =   User_profile.objects.create(address = address ,city=city,country=country,zipcode=zipcode,dob=dob,gender=gender,weight=weight,height=height)
                   
                      user.save()
                   
                      return render(request,'app/userProfile.html')

                    else:
                      print ('login first')
           else:
                 return render(request,'app/login.html')
          
 
    else: 
          return render(request,'app/login.html')
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#saving-changes-to-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to use update instead
assuming that email really equals to the user id

```
User_profile.objects.filter(email = userid).update(
    address=address,
    city=city,
    country=country,
    zipcode=zipcode,
    dob=dob,
    gender=gender,
    weight=weight,
    height=height
)
```